# Installing Gnome alongside with MOFO!!

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-gnome

Can I share the same home (partition) and Swap for both installations; or each has to have its own ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need free (unpartitioned) space on your drive (you can create that by resizing your existing partitions using for example [gparted](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GParted/)). Then during the installation you need to choose the option, which says something like "innstall ubuntu next to an existing os". during the partitioning yout tell to use the free space on the drive.

in the end you will be able to chose the os during boot in grub, with having one os as the default one, which will be started, when no input was given after a few seconds.